# How to add an onclick function to a button in Hippo Animator

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, web-animations

I wonder if you are familiar with *Hippo Animator*.. This software can create web animation easily and basically you can add html buttons and etc to it. Now currently I have added a button and on it's properties I need to add an On Click function so the whenever a user clicked on it, it should redirect to another site location. I have tried several ways such as this one:

```
location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
```

But an error comes up that says:

**The variable location could not be found.**

Note that I can't try `document.getElementById` because this software does not support it...

And here's the picture of my workspace:

[image: print screen]

So if you know how can I add an On Click function that can redirect the page to another site in this software ,please let me know. I would really appreciate that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place that into the OnClick of the Button:

`GetTopUrl("www.google.com");`

Keep Rocking!